# Is there a transitive phrasal verb for dance?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, phrasal-verbs

I am looking for a transitive phrasal verb that means "danced X dance"

> He spun out the Duck dance in front of everyone.

I don't think spun out a dance is idiomatic. I am looking for something like that, but that's idiomatic.

Maybe "put out", but I am thinking there might be better options?

Comment: Is the word "dance" a necessary part of the dance's name? It is very common to say things like, "He danced the waltz" or "He danced the hokey pokey."

Comment: I am not sure, but in informal speech it sounds better if you use a phrasal verb.

Comment: This sounds like the kind of thing where you might be able to get creative. In theory, "spin out" could work. The only problem is that it already has a fixed meaning. We (Americans, anyway) use it to describe things that spin *out of control*—like a car on ice.

Comment: In a formal register, we might say he performed the dance or executed the dance.  Informally, he did it.  A phrasal idiom like "to trot out" could fit (he put the dance on display yet again) but I can't think of a dance-specific idiom offhand.

Comment: To me (UK) _spun out_ suggests 'made the dance last an unusually long time'.